# Was bedeutet der "Naja-Ton"?

Tags: inflection

Mir ist aufgefallen, dass manche Deutsche manchmal mit einem Tonfall sprechen, den ich gerade *Naja-Ton* genannt habe.

Beispiel:

*Karl ist auf Besuch bei seiner Mutter. Eigentlich hatte er mehr Lust auf Motorrad fahren, da heute der erste Tag seit lange ohne Regen ist. Direkt nach dem Abendessen, sagt er:*

> Danke für das Essen. Wäre es dir recht, dass wir den Kaffee heute ausfallen lassen? Ich würde gerne noch etwas erledigen.

*Die Mutter antwortete enttäuscht (mit Naja-Tonfall).*

> Kein Problem, wir sehen uns aber nächste Woche auf jeden Fall!

Was bedeutet der *Naja-Ton*? Wie beeinflusst er die Bedeutung eines Satz? In welche Zusammenhängen kann man ihn benutzen?

Comment: Ich habe nicht die geringste Ahnung, was Du meinst.
Insbesondere ist mir der Zusammenhang von "Naja" mit
"an Kind gerichteter Tonfall" vollkommen unklar.
Könntest Du das bitte nochmal genauer (bzw. mit anderen Worten) erklären?

Comment: @Uwe Ja, es ist schwer, aber kann versuchen! Dieser Tonfall klingt ein Bisschen kindlich für mich, aber ich bin Norwegisch XD. Der Tonfall ist vielleicht nicht genau wie "Baby-Ton", sondern irgendwo inzwischen das und Normalton. Würde es sinn machen, ob man diesen speziellen Tonfall anstelle von "naja" benutzen konnte, und dass der ganze Satz diesfalls mit "naja" einsetzt wurde?

Comment: Gib bitte mal zwei komplette Sätze an,
bei denen Du diesen Tonfall empfindest:
einen, der an ein Kind gerichtet ist, und einen, der an einen
Erwachsenen gerichtet ist und bei dem Du den gleichen Tonfall
wahrnimmst. Geht es Dir um die Sprachmelodie, die Lautstärke, die
Betonung, oder um was sonst?

Comment: Zur Klarstellung: Meinst Du wirklich "Naja" , oder meinst Du
["Na"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/na_Interjektion_Partikel)
(möglicherweise auch langgezogen)? Wenn ich mich an ein Kind wende,
würde ich den Satz kaum mit "naja" anfangen, aber häufig mit "na".

Comment: Ich denke wir müssen vergessen dieses mit Kindern, es war nicht zum Thema gehörig. Aber ich habe gerade versucht ein Beispiel zu machen. Vielleicht ist es nur komplett Blödsinn, aber es ist einen Versuch wert :-P Tatsächlich, wenn ich nachdenke, konnte der Tonfall auch vielleicht  "enttäuscht" bedeuten.

Comment: @Atle, ich habe einige Fehler im Deutschen korrigiert und zum Teil das Deutsch umgeschrieben, dass es "natürlicher" klingt. Ich hoffe, ich habe den Sinn nicht zu sehr verändert, vorallem beim letzten Satz. Könntest du das bitte prüfen. Wenn du Fragen zu meinen Änderungen hast, erkläre ich auch gerne mehr!

Comment: @Iris: Um "naja" zu benutzen: Naja, klingt ganz formell! :-)

Comment: @Alte, ich bin mir nicht sicher, was du meinst. Du findest meine Änderungen nicht gut? Falls ja, ändere es ruhig zurück.

Comment: Ich mein natürlich @Atle nicht Alte. Ich bitte um Verzeihung!

Comment: OT: Müsste das "*seit lange*" nicht "*seit langem*" heissen?

Answer (score 5):

*Naja* drückt eigentlich eher eine Art Skepsis aus. Das bedeutet, dass derjenige, der das *naja* sagt, nicht von der Aussage des Vorsprechers überzeugt ist.

Beispiel:

> A: Was hältst davon, wenn wir davor noch mal schnell in der Eisdiele vorbeischauen?
>
> B: Naja, eigentlich bin ich schon satt, außerdem vertrage ich doch kein Eis.

*Naja* kann aber auch bei Geschichten eingefügt werden, wenn man abgelenkt wurde und den eigentlichen Verlauf wieder aufnimmt.

Beispiel:

> Ich bin dann mit dem Peter zur Eisdiele gegangen. Kennst du Peter? Das ist der Kräftige, der eigentlich immer ein Eis in der Hand hat. Naja, auf jeden Fall sind wir dahin gegangen und unterwegs hat er sich dann ein Eis aus der Hosentasche gezogen...

Die erste Variante kann etwas von oben herab wirken, da Leute die Einleitung *Naja* auch nutzen, wenn sie auf jeden Fall dagegen sind, es aber nicht so offen zugeben wollen. Dadurch kann es so wirken, als würde man von oben herab auf den anderen reagieren.

Die zweite Variante ist auf jeden Fall nicht dazu geeignet, in irgendeiner Weise zur Herablassung zu dienen.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung! Aber was mit dem Tonfall? :)

Comment: @Atle das von *oben herab* kann man am besten mit *condescending* übersetzen. Das wäre eine Art Tonfall.

Comment: Verstehe "von oben herab" :) Meinst du dass man oft auch einen anderen Tonfall (phonetisch) zusammen mit "naja" benutzt?

Comment: @Atle naja, man kann das auch unsicher oder auch recht neutral sagen.

Answer (score 0):

Bezogen auf oben genannten Text ist wohl ein enttäuschter Tonfall gemeint.

Die Mutter hätte gerne noch mehr Zeit mit ihrem Sohn verbracht, aber dieser will und/oder kann gerade keine Zeit für eine gemeinsame Aktivität aufbringen.